# React native how to draw a curve

Tags: react-native

How you draw this curve:

[image]

I thought to make one `absolute` positionod round view with `white` background and place two other on both sides. But this way it is almost impossible to achieve perfect curve.

Comment: May this video will help you. https://youtu.be/6LsLgHeX500

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot

Comment: @KishanBharda If you had posted it as answer I would marked as correct answer coz I have watched that video and it helped!

Comment: I posted it as answer. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://youtu.be/6LsLgHeX500) is the video tutorial. It will help to create same UI.

[image]